# Time derivative of a line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question**:
What is the derivative of

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}^{(x,y,z)} \vec{F}(x,y,z,t) \cdot d\vec{r}$$

Now in order to compute any single integral, I need to give you a path. So far, all we know is that we are integrating $\vec{F}$ from the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to the point $(x, y, z)$ along some path. Let me specify that path. What is the derivative of

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{t_0}^{t} \vec{F}(c(t),t) \cdot \vec{c}\;'(t)dt $$

where $c(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$ is the path and $\vec{c}\;'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t), z'(t))$ is the tangent vector to the path.

**Thoughts**: Derivatives require a path. You can't take a derivative unless you know what path you are taking the derivative over. Likewise, integrals/antiderivatives require a path. You can't create an antiderivative unless you know what path you are doing the integral over. If I created the antiderivative

$$\int_{t_0}^{t} \vec{F}(c(t)) \cdot \vec{c}\;'(t)dt $$

This would be the antiderivative over the path $c(t)$. Therefore if I take the derivative $d/dt$, this indicates the derivative over the same path $c(t)$. And since we know derivatives and antiderivatives are inverse operations (*over the same path*),

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{t_0}^{t} \vec{F}(c(t)) \cdot \vec{c}\;'(t)dt = \vec{F}(c(t)) \cdot \vec{c}\;'(t)$$

That's what I think at least. **My problem** is that my integrand involves an extra $t$ (I'm asking this because in order to understand time-dependent forces and energy consequences in physics, I'd like to understand derivatives of line integrals).

**Useful break down of my question**:
These would be useful to solve. Just to make the problem look simpler, what is
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(t),y(t))x'(t)dt $$ This is the antiderivative over the path $x(t)$. But the derivative $d/dt$ is with respect to the path $(x(t), y(t))$. So would this become, using the chain rule

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \Bigg [\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(t),y(t))x'(t)dt\Bigg]\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Bigg[\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(t),y(t))x'(t)dt\Bigg]\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Is the second bracket zero? **Another useful, simpler looking, problem**:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{t_0}^t f(x(t),t)x'(t)dt $$

Which might become:
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \Bigg [\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(t), t)x'(t)dt\Bigg]\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Bigg[\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(t), t)x'(t)dt\Bigg]\frac{dt}{dt}$$

Is the first bracket just $f(x(t),t)$? If I write this first bracket as 
$$ \int_{x_0}^x f(x, t)dx$$ Then a $\partial/\partial x$ of this antiderivative should return $f(x,t)$. However **I'm getting confused by the abstraction of everything and the actual computation**. This last integral seems to imply that the path is just the $x$-axis. But the real path is $x(t)$. You need to do the integral with all $t$'s then. But I still feel like
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_{t_0}^{t} f(x(t), t) x'(t)dt = f(x(t),t) ?$$

If you read all of this, thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest you to avoid using the same letter as the limit of integration and a variable (for example integrating from $t_0$ to $t$ with respect to $t$.). It's commonly used in physics, but the mathematicians don't like it.

Comment: It's somewhat confusing what you're asking. Perhaps you could give a concrete problem. It seems like you want to know the time derivative of the energy of a particle, where the energy is obtained by integrating a time dependent force along the particle's path. Is that correct?

Comment: @juanarroyo That is correct. Just to make things simple, I won't talk about potential energy or total energy, but just kinetic energy. (The idea of total energy just comes from the work-kinetic energy theorem where you move all conservative stuff to one side of the equal sign, leaving all non-conservative stuff on the other side of the equal sign. Also potential energy is just the name given to the "force side" of the work-kinetic energy theorem if the force is conservative. If it's non-conservative, it has no name). So consider a force $\vec{F}$ acting on a particle. The work done

Comment: @juanarroyo by that force is $W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$. By the work-kinetic energy theorem, $\int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ is equal to the total change in kinetic energy $T$ between the final and initial points of that path. The inst rate of change of energy $dT/dt = d/dt \int\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$. This is the rate at which the force is doing work (instantaneous rate at which energy flows in or out). From my work above, $dT/dt = \vec{F}(c(t))\cdot\vec{c}'(t) = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$ where $\vec{v}$ is instantaneous velocity. We get told that power $P$ is $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$. This

Comment: @juanarroyo is where it comes from. And note that the above didn't depend on $\vec{F}$ being conservative or not. My problem is that for time-dependent forces, I want to know what $dT/dt = d/dt \int \vec{F}(c(t),t)\cdot \vec{c}'(t)dt$ is. It won't be $\vec{F}(c(t),t) \cdot \vec{c}'(t)$. My feeling is that I have to use the chain rule. The Power formula for a time-dependent force will take a different form.

Comment: Why won't it be that? Better yet, how do you know that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{t_0}^{t} \vec{F}(c(t)) \cdot \vec{c}\;'(t)dt = \vec{F}(c(t)) \cdot \vec{c}\;'(t)$?

Comment: @juanarroyo Yeah I think you're right. I'm going to have to think about this some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a time dependent vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z,t)$, and for a curve $\vec{c}(s)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you're interested in the integral of $\vec{F}$  along $\vec{c}$ from $s=t_0$ to $s=\hat{t}$. Notice I'm using a different symbol for the argument of $c$; $c$ maps into the domain of $\vec{F}$ so strictly speaking you should use a different symbol for its argument if you're going to compose the functions. Also, different symbols must be used for the limits of integration. Now, you're interested in the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{d\hat{t}}\int_{t_0}^\hat{t}\vec{F}(\vec{c}(s),s)\cdot\vec{c}'(s)ds$$

But this is just the fundamental theorem of calculus from single variable calculus: the expression inside the integral is a single variable function of $s$ (a dot product gives you a real number), which we are integrating, and then differentiating with respect to one of the limits of integration. All we need to know is that the integrand meets the criterion required by the FTC. Since this is physics, $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{c}$ are probably differentiable or at least continuous, and the dot product of two continuous functions is again continuous, which makes the integrand continuous, which is good enough to make the FTC work. The result is

$$\frac{d}{d\hat{t}}\int_{t_0}^\hat{t}\vec{F}(\vec{c}(s),s)\cdot\vec{c}'(s)ds=\vec{F}(\vec{c}(\hat{t}),\hat{t})\cdot\vec{c}'(\hat{t})$$

Answer (score 1):

You don’t always need the path. That depends on the nature of the force. If it is a conservative force, then the integral is path independent. In other words, if $\vec{F}=\nabla \varphi$ in some domain for some $\varphi$, then $$\int_{c_1} \vec{F} = \int_{c_2} \vec{F}$$ where $c_1,c_2$ are paths in that domain. (Easily proved by applying Stokes’ theorem).

An example is if the sole force acting on a body is gravity.  The work done (and thus the change in energy) between points A and B can be computed by just knowing the points A and B. It doesn’t matter which path was taken.

So then the integral and its derivative can be taken without knowing the path. In your case, do you know anything like that about the force?

Comment: In my case since the force depends on time, it will be non-conservative. You can see this by taking a path that back-tracks on itself before reaching the endpoint. For conservative forces, the back-track section perfectly cancels a "forward" section, and therefore this path is completely equivalent to just taking a straight line path. But because my force is time-dependent, such "back-tracking" won't be equal and opposite to a "forward" section. Therefore this path and a straight line path give different results and time-dependent forces are non-conservative.

Comment: Thank you for your response by the way. I'll just also add that even with conservative forces, you have to be careful. Consider a conservative force $f(x)$ (actually I think all integrable functions from single-variable calculus are conservative). Different paths will give the same result. But the derivative will change depending on the path you take. $\int f(x(t)) x'(t)dt = \int f(x_2(t))x'_2(t)dt$ if the start and end points are the same. But $d/dt \int f(x(t))x'(t)dt = f(x(t)) x'(t)$, which will be different from $d/dt \int f(x_2(t))x_2'(t)dt = f(x_2(t)) x_2'(t)$